# Typescript warning "Cannot find module" importing AntDesign components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, antd

My environment consists in Webpack 4.16, React 16.4, TypeScript 3.3 and AntDesign 3.13

Everything works fine, I can import each component from AntD in order to optimize better my files and the final size.

I'm also using **webpack-bundle-analyzer** to check the size for each import I'm doing.

My problem is a warning that I'm getting on my editor:

[image: Cannot find antd module]

How to add my node_modules libs in order to not get the warning? Why is it working even without finding the module?

---

**UPDATE 1**

In order to understand it better, I'm applying some WebPack configurations to see if has any results:

```
const getResolves = {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.less'],
  modules: ['src/less', 'src/ts', 'src', 'node_modules'],
  alias: {
    antd: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/antd'),
  }
};
```

I tried to add an alias to **antd** lib. It works normally like before, but the warning is still there.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Good news! I could found a way to make it work and this post is updated with an answer. I will let the question open in order to see if anyone else has a different approach or a better explanation about it.

---

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ant Design do you use?

Comment: It's on my post... 3.13

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution presented by this guy here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25312#issuecomment-449609664

I just added a new property **"moduleResolution": "node"** to my tsconfig file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using webpack latest version (alpha version) then you will found this issue , dont update react scripts untill using webpack stable version .

antd lib has some limitation , it is not compitable with vite till no

Another sussgestion If you are trying to integrate vite in react then wait for the latest stable version of webpack , and also react is bring that feature in version 18 or above